# Why I get This DOM Error?

Tags: magento2, error, adminhtml, system.xml

My system.xml in /etc/adminhtml is the reason for this error

```
<field id="vendor_role" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
    <label>User Roles</label><source_model>Admin\Role\Model\System\Config\Source\Roles</source_model>
</field>

 Warning: DOMXPath::query(): Invalid expression in /home/mysite/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php on line 273
```

Comment: So did you get the solution?

Comment: No @ShireenN can you help me

Answer (score 1):

Since the vendor directory is generated automatically, I would try deleting the vendor directory and running `composer install` again. Also `magento setup:upgrade` once that happens (confirm database is up to data with package versions). `magento cache:clean` and reload your store front.

Beyond that, I would review the [steps for creating admin configuration entries](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/create-system-xml-configuration-magento-2.html).

Comment: I can't understand because I'm learning magento 2 from past month only. Can you pls elaborate me.